# Use regex to extract unit number

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of descriptions and I want to extract the unit information using regular expression

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UR6a_wZ8ido&index=29&list=PLlRFEj9H3Oj4JXIwMwN1_ss1Tk8wZShEJ) on regex and here's what I got

```
import re
x = ["Four 10-story towers - five 11-story residential towers around Lake Peterson - two 9-story hotel towers facing Devon Avenue & four levels of retail below the hotels",
     "265 rental units",
     "10 stories and contain 200 apartments",
     "801 residential properties that include row homes, town homes, condos, single-family housing, apartments, and senior rental units",
     "4-unit townhouse building (6,528 square feet of living space & 2,755 square feet of unheated garage)"]
unit=[]
for item in x:
    extract = re.findall('[0-9]+.unit',item)
    unit.append(extract)
print unit
```

This works with string ends in unit, but I also strings end with `'rental unit','apartment','bed'` and other as in this example. 
I could do this with multiple regex, but is there a way to do this within one regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Use group: `(?:rental unit|apartment|bed)` instead of fixed word

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this. Again, thanks!

Comment: If you do not know the list of units, you can't use just regex. Say, you can use `r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?[\s-]\w+`, but it will just grab `801 residential`, not `801 residential properties`. Regex is not that smart.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate a bit more please? Sorry that I'm new to regex. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.. I only need the number of unit though, but I wanted to be sure I'm extracting the real unit rather than # of stories/parking lot etc. Thanks again!

Comment: What is your expected output? Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/h8wXop).

Comment: I guess by "unit" it means something like `square feet`.  The `unit` in `4-unit` is not really a unit ;)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your not afraid of making a hideously long regex you could use something to the extent of:

```
compiled_re = re.compile(ur"(\d*)-unit|(\d*)\srental unit|(\d*)\sbed|(\d*)\sappartment")
unit = []
for item in x:
    extract = re.findall(compiled_re, item)
    unit.append(extract)
```

You would have to extend the regex pattern with a new "|" followed by a search pattern for each possible type of reference to unit numbers.  Unfortunately, if there is very low consistency in the entries this approach would become basically unusable.

Also, might I suggest using a regex tester like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).  It really helps determining if your regex will do what you want it to.